# Get Users count who has visited all 4 weeks of a month and has visited 5 minimum Days in SQL

Tags: mysql, group-by

user_visits

```
user_id  | created_at
1     2021-04-02
1     2021-04-08
1     2021-04-15
1     2021-04-21
1     2021-04-21
1     2021-04-22
1     2021-04-25
2     2021-04-21
2     2021-05-02
```

I want to get the result of users who satisfies the following conditons:

- User should have visited atleast 4 times in all the weeks of that
  following month
  User 1 has visited on 02,08,15,21 all weeks of
  April.
- User should have visited 5 unique days and User 1 also satisifies the
  above condition

and the result would be something like this

```
Eligigle_User_Count | Month
1                     April
```

I tried a lot to find a solution, used lots of grouping but could not reach a solution. Hope someone will help me!

Comment: what is "that following month"?  explain.  and you need to define what a "week" is.  and if a month has 5 or 6 weeks or parts of weeks, what do they need to meet your criterion?

Comment: please do show some of the things you've tried; it will immensely help us help you

Comment: I was able to get the no of days user has visited in one query, then I was able to get number of user who has visited atleast once in every 4 week in another query but i was  not able to merge them all together and due to frustration I just don't find them all useful and deleted all the SQL I wrote. It felt like I'm doing the entire thing wrong.

Comment: What is your primary key?

Comment: user_id is the primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to be messy but functional. The basic query for this isn't complex:

```
SELECT
  v.user_id,
  weekly_visits.month
FROM
  user_visits v
  JOIN (/* weekly visits query */) weekly_visits
  JOIN (/* unique days query */) daily_visits
WHERE
  weekly_visits.weeks_visited >= 4
  AND daily_visits.unique_days >= 5
GROUP BY
  v.user_id,
  weekly_visits.month;
```

So we just need to determine the `weekly visits` and `unique days` queries. Given some example data:

```
CREATE TABLE user_visits (
  `user_id` VARCHAR(16),
  `created_at` date
);

INSERT INTO user_visits
  (`user_id`, `created_at`)
VALUES
  /* user 1 should be returned */
  ('1', '2021-04-02'),
  ('1', '2021-04-08'),
  ('1', '2021-04-15'),
  ('1', '2021-04-21'),
  ('1', '2021-04-21'),
  ('1', '2021-04-22'),
  ('1', '2021-04-25'),

  /* user 2 should be returned */
  ('2', '2021-04-01'),
  ('2', '2021-04-07'),
  ('2', '2021-04-14'),
  ('2', '2021-04-20'),
  ('2', '2021-04-20'),
  ('2', '2021-04-21'),
  ('2', '2021-04-24'),

  /* user 3 only visits 4 days in April, don't return */
  ('3', '2021-04-07'),
  ('3', '2021-04-14'),
  ('3', '2021-04-20'),
  ('3', '2021-04-24'),

  /* user 4 only visits 2 weeks in April, don't return */
  ('4', '2021-04-01'),
  ('4', '2021-04-02'),
  ('4', '2021-04-03'),
  ('4', '2021-04-04'),
  ('4', '2021-04-05'),
  ('4', '2021-04-06'),
  ('4', '2021-04-07'),
  ('4', '2021-04-08'),
  ('4', '2021-04-09');
```

Breaking this down into more manageable steps using temporary tables to keep track of these separate steps will keep the end result cleaner.

MySQL has a `WEEK()` function (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) and a `DATE_FORMAT()` function (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) that should be useful to start. We can group by `WEEK(created_at)` and count those rows to convert the dates to weeks visited.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE unique_weeks
  SELECT
    user_id,
    WEEK(created_at) as week,
    DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%M %Y") as month
  FROM
    user_visits
  GROUP BY
    user_id,
    WEEK(created_at),
    DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%M %Y");

SELECT * FROM unique_weeks;
```

| user_id | week | month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 13 | April 2021 |
| 1 | 14 | April 2021 |
| 1 | 15 | April 2021 |
| 1 | 16 | April 2021 |
| 1 | 17 | April 2021 |
| 2 | 13 | April 2021 |
| 2 | 14 | April 2021 |
| 2 | 15 | April 2021 |
| 2 | 16 | April 2021 |
| 3 | 14 | April 2021 |
| 3 | 15 | April 2021 |
| 3 | 16 | April 2021 |
| 4 | 13 | April 2021 |
| 4 | 14 | April 2021 |

Now we can query on this table after grouping/counting the different weeks by user:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE weekly_visits
  SELECT
    user_id,
    COUNT(week) as weeks_visited,
    month
  FROM unique_weeks
  GROUP BY user_id, month;

SELECT * FROM weekly_visits;
```

| user_id | weeks_visited | month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | April 2021 |
| 2 | 4 | April 2021 |
| 3 | 3 | April 2021 |
| 4 | 2 | April 2021 |

To determine how many unique days a user has visited, that's a separate query using `GROUP BY` and `COUNT`:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE daily_visits
  SELECT
    user_id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT created_at) as unique_days
    DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%M %Y") as month
  FROM
    user_visits
  GROUP BY
    user_id,
    DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%M %Y");

SELECT * FROM daily_visits;
```

| user_id | unique_days | month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 | April 2021 |
| 2 | 6 | April 2021 |
| 3 | 4 | April 2021 |
| 4 | 9 | April 2021 |

So to put it all together, you can join all of these on `user_id` with the 2 conditions:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE eligible_users
  SELECT
    v.user_id,
    weekly_visits.month
  FROM
    user_visits v
    JOIN weekly_visits ON weekly_visits.user_id = v.user_id
    JOIN daily_visits ON daily_visits.user_id = v.user_id
  WHERE
    weekly_visits.weeks_visited >= 4
    AND daily_visits.unique_days >= 5
  GROUP BY
    v.user_id,
    weekly_visits.month;

SELECT * FROM eligible_users;
```

To get you:

| user_id | month |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | April 2021 |
| 2 | April 2021 |

If you want a COUNT of the user_ids instead of the actual user_ids, then `GROUP BY month` in the final query.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) as num_eligible_users,
  month
FROM eligible_users
GROUP BY month;
```

| num_eligible_users | month |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | April 2021 |

Working example at https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wRRBaEkhtX911RLcUg1ysV/5

Comment: Thank you! It will take at least a day for me to understand what you've written here!
 I'll get back to this answer! thanks a ton!

Comment: I tried to break it down into distinct steps to help explain the process. Good luck!

Comment: It worked but I'm not able to group it by month, year. I've worked very little on queries. That's why I'm asking all these. Could you tell me how I can show it like May 2021 (Grouping) ?

Comment: I've used DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%M %Y') AS month in the select statement. The user count is incorrect when used with 1000+ rows. Not sure why

Comment: If you change ALL of the `MONTHNAME(created_at)` to `DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%M %Y")` it should give you `April 2021` as the final output (https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wRRBaEkhtX911RLcUg1ysV/1). My advice for debugging with 1000+ rows is to start small to try to get the expected output for the first 2 tables in my answer, then you can build the query up from there.

Comment: Also, the query becomes simpler if you use temporary tables instead of subqueries. Additionally, I added some more test data to show how users 3 and 4 get excluded based on the conditions in the last query. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wRRBaEkhtX911RLcUg1ysV/3

Comment: I just updated the `daily_visits` query to count `DISTINCT` days instead of # of visits. So users 1 and 2 should return 6 distinct days now instead of 7.

Comment: I've updated the Fiddle.
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7fsq2Z4MNkg3pVH8bDdqNG/1

@WOUNDEDStevenJones

Comment: I've added a follow up question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67601339/get-the-count-of-users-who-has-visited-all-the-4-weeks-in-a-month

@WOUNDEDStevenJones Could you please help!